# Group months as season

Tags: mysql, group-by, rows

I am stuck on a mysql query. I was wondering how I can group by multiple rows. I got the months and I wanted to group them together by season, so for example I want to show the crime count by adding all the crimes in the month from 01-03 and show this as winter etc.

this is the code I currently have

```
SELECT d.month, SUM(c.crimeCount)
FROM FYP_Date d JOIN FYP_Crime c
WHERE d.dateID=c.dateID
GROUP BY month
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using a `case` statement with `month`:

```
select case when month(d.month) in (1,2,3) then 'q1',
            when month(d.month) in (4,5,6) then 'q2',
            when month(d.month) in (7,8,9) then 'q3',
            when month(d.month) in (10,11,12) then 'q4'
       end as quarter,
       SUM(c.crimeCount)
FROM FYP_Date d 
    JOIN FYP_Crime c ON d.dateID=c.dateID
GROUP BY 1
```

Also please note -- when joining, use  `on` to match your records instead of using `where`.

Comment: Won't work (at least with my MySQL) because `select month('2016-01');` gives `NULL`. But +1 for the JOIN…ON.

Comment: @PerlDog -- ah, I assumed it was a date field -- didn't see the edits.  The month would have to be converted accordingly if that's the case.  I actually prefer your solution -- never used `quarter` before.  +1 to you for that!

Comment: Actually I haven't either. :-) Never needed it. Yours has the benefit that the OP can change the values to e.g. `... in (11,12,1) then 'winter'`.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the [QUARTER](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter) function is of help here:

```
select quarter(concat(d.month,'-01')) as qrt, 
       sum(c.crimecount)
  from fyp_date d join fyp_crime c on d.dateid=c.dateid
 group by qrt;
```

This is not the same as *season* but it's quite close. I assume your `month` column is `char` so I appended a `'-01'` for the calculation because `quarter` needs (at least) a day to work with.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT d.month, SUM(c.crimeCount), CONVERT(LEFT(d.month, 4), SIGNED) AS y, CONVERT(RIGHT(d.month, 2), SIGNED) AS m, CEIL(CONVERT(RIGHT(d.month, 2), SIGNED)/3) AS q 
FROM FYP_Date d JOIN FYP_Crime c WHERE d.dateID=c.dateID GROUP BY q;
```

For year and quarter you have to compine "y" and "q"

```
SELECT d.month, SUM(c.crimeCount), CONVERT(LEFT(d.month, 4), SIGNED) AS y, CONVERT(RIGHT(d.month, 2), SIGNED) AS m, CEIL(CONVERT(RIGHT(d.month, 2), SIGNED)/3) AS q 
FROM FYP_Date d JOIN FYP_Crime c WHERE d.dateID=c.dateID GROUP BY y, q;
```

The original question was how to convert month to quarter, which was edited (see pictures). The solution for this is:

```
SELECT d.month, SUM(c.crimeCount), CEIL(month/3) AS q 
FROM FYP_Date d JOIN FYP_Crime c WHERE d.dateID=c.dateID GROUP BY q
```

After defining column "month" to "year-month", the solution is mentioned above (updated).

Comment: @recycler  update your answer ... as per amaze3 is not working